# NFS share group permission not respected

Tags: linux, freebsd, nfs4

I have a linux client and freebsd nfs server (NAS4free actually)
NFS share is mounted by fstab this way:

```
server:/mnt/disk/ZHomeData on /data type nfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=20,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountvers=3,mountport=705,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none)
```

On the client and server I have the same UID and **GUID**

UID permission works well, but I cannot access files or directories where only group matches.

Here is a shell session:

```
artiom@client /data/BACKUP % ls -l
total 1030151
drwx------ 2 artiom family          3 Feb 16  2014 Drivers
drwxr-x--- 5 yulia  family          5 Jul 27  2014 mac
artiom@client /data/BACKUP % id
uid=1000(artiom) gid=1000(artiom) groups=1000(artiom),1001(family)
artiom@client /data/BACKUP % cd Drivers 
artiom@client /data/BACKUP/Drivers
 % cd ..
artiom@client /data/BACKUP % cd mac 
cd: permission denied: mac
artiom@client /data/BACKUP % 


[artiom@nfs /mnt/disk/ZHomeData/BACKUP]$ ls -l
total 1030151
drwx------  2 artiom  family           3 Feb 16  2014 Drivers
drwxr-x---  5 1001    family           5 Jul 27  2014 mac

id artiom
uid=1000(artiom) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel),80(www),1001(family)

[artiom@nfs /mnt/disk/ZHomeData/BACKUP]$ cd Drivers/
[artiom@nfs /mnt/disk/ZHomeData/BACKUP/Drivers]$ cd ..
[artiom@nfs /mnt/disk/ZHomeData/BACKUP]$ cd mac/
[artiom@nfs /mnt/disk/ZHomeData/BACKUP/mac]$
```